# What is the probability that a randomly chosen function is even or odd?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

While answering my friend's question about functions, I said "Most of the functions are not even nor odd." without thinking so much. Now I wonder how accurate this statement is, that is, I want to know the answer of the following question:

> Let $S$ be the set of all functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. What is the probability that a randomly chosen function from this set is even or odd?

At first I thought of this subset of $S$ as "very small", but after realizing that both even ones and odd ones should have the same "size" with the set of all functions from $\mathbb R^+\cup\{0\}$ to $\mathbb R$ (with $f(0)=0$ for the odd ones), it seemed bigger. I am not very familiar with probability on uncountable sets, but I want to know any explanations you can make, thank you.

Comment: Define a probability measure over $S$ and then mayve we could think about an answer

Comment: @TitoEliatron That is what I meant when I said I was not familiar, sorry if the question does not make sense.

Comment: Under any reasonable interpretation of the problem, the probability of getting an even function as well as the probability of getting an odd function should be zero.  Consider a distribution where the values of $f(x)$ are each independently chosen over some continuous distribution.  Now consider very specifically the values of $f(1)$ and $f(-1)$.  Given a choice of $f(1)$ there are uncountably infinitely many choices of $f(-1)$, only one of which would not prevent $f$ from being even or odd respectively and uncountably infinitely many of them will prevent $f$ from being either even or odd.

Comment: Of course, you may define some distribution which is not continuous over the set of functions which might have a different result... such as in the extreme case of a trivial distribution like "*always picking the constant function $f(x)=0$ for all $x$*" in which case you have a $100\%$ chance of picking an even and odd function.

Comment: @JMoravitz That makes sense, thank you. By the way, should I delete the question since it does not make so much sense?

Comment: Please don't delete the question.  Others may benefit from seeing why the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Okay, I will not delete it.

Comment: @Tan Instead of deleting the question, you could write JMoravitz's comment into an answer and accept it. That would be the proper thing to do (it would remove an unanswered question from the site, and make the answer more visible to someone who found it via search).